# Passing Variables to Ansible from Py script

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, variables, ansible

I am unable to pass variables in ansible

Here is my python script

```
import csv
import json
data=
file = 'splunkapps.csv'
json_file = 'output_file_name.json'

def read_CSV(file, json_file):
    csv_rows = []
    with open(file) as csvfile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
        field = reader.fieldnames
        for row in reader:
            csv_rows.extend([{field[i]:row[field[i]] for i in range(len(field))}])
        convert_write_json(csv_rows, json_file)

def convert_write_json(data, json_file):
    with open(json_file, "w") as f:
        f.write(json.dumps(data, sort_keys=False, indent=4, separators=(',', ': '))) 

read_CSV(file,json_file)
with open('output_file_name.json') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)
    for p in data:
        print('AppName: ' + p['AppName'])
        print('Host: ' + p['Host'])
        print('SealID: ' + p['SealID'])
        print('')
```

And my Ansible script is

Yaml file:

```
---
- name: Onboard app
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
  - name:
    script: spl.py
    register: result
  - debug:
      msg: "{{ result.stdout_lines }}"
    with_items: "{{ modules }}"

  - name: print user name and password
    shell: |
      echo {{ modules['AppName'] }}
      echo {{ modules['Host'] }}
```

I have to use 2.3 version of ansible and currently i am using 2.7 version of py

Answer (score 0):

> Q: *"Passing Variables to Ansible from Py script"*

A: It's possible to use *lookup, pipe, from_yaml* and assign the output of a script to a variable. For example with the script

```
$ cat my_script
#!/bin/sh
printf 'AppName: my_AppName\n'
printf 'Host: my_Host\n'
printf 'SealID: my_SealID\n'
```

the playbook

```
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    my_var: "{{ lookup('pipe', 'my_script')|from_yaml }}"
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: my_var
    - debug:
        msg: "AppName [{{ my_var.AppName }}]"
```

gives

```
ok: [localhost] => 
  my_var:
    AppName: my_AppName
    Host: my_Host
    SealID: my_SealID

ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: AppName [my_AppName]
```

---

> Q: *"Ansible 2.3 doesn't have `lookup` plugin. What will be the alternate way for this?"*

A: It' possible to *register* the output of the script and *combine* the dictionary *with_items*. For example, the play below gives the same result

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - script: my_script
      register: result
    - set_fact:
        my_var: "{{ my_var|default({})|combine(item|from_yaml) }}"
      with_items: "{{ result.stdout_lines }}"
    - debug:
        var: my_var
    - debug:
        msg: "AppName [{{ my_var.AppName }}]"
```

---

Notes

There is no variable `modules`. This is probably the error

```
  - debug:
      msg: "{{ result.stdout_lines }}"
    with_items: "{{ modules }}"
```

The registered output should be simply printed

```
  - debug:
      msg: "{{ result.stdout_lines }}"
```

Comment: I am still trying, 2.3 does't have lookup plugin https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.3/list_of_all_modules.html  what will be the alternate way for this?  If not a script directly passing variables from a json or csv or txt in a remote server. I have 10-30 Appnames, so i am hard to get through this

Comment: It's possible to "combine" the registered lines. I've updated the answer.

Comment: fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "Unexpected failure in finding the lookup named '{{ result.stdout_lines }}' in the available lookup plugins"}

Comment: This error caused probably the `loop` directive introduced in Ansible 2.5. I've changed it to `with_items`. FYI, Ansible's policy is to support the last 3 versions. At the moment it is 2.9, 2.8 and 2.7.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I am stuck for days on this. It is really working awesome in local host. But when i did the same in a remote host why there are errors, Any idea on it? can i take my_script from a remote and pass variables?

Comment: @Sumanth, It's absolutely necessary that you invest your time in a question that might be answered. Read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), edit and update the question with the current code and with the error messages. Reduce the Python script to simple print statements. To solve your problem it's not necessary to learn how you get the data. Do not waste the time of the people who want to help you.